# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: error, magento-1, core

Huge error as soon as I try to view any page on my magento site now displays:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in  /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1227
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1239 
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdFieldName() on a non-object in    /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 151

If anyone knows what is causing this you will be saving my life.

Comment: First try to clear the cache. If that doesn't change anything, try to disable one by one the custom extensions you have installed. Maybe there is a "faulty" one. For further assistance check this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/428/146

Comment: Was this solved?

Comment: Can you tell me what Magento version this is? It's not CE 1.7, I'm pretty sure about that

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem while installing an instance of Magento within our testing environment.  Because I downloaded Magento Enterprise on my local machine and pushed the code to the test environment using GIT, my `.gitignore` file left out the `enterprise.xml` and `config.xml`.  Because these files were missing it generated the error message described by the OP.  Once in place, it sent me to the Magento Install page!  Hope that helps someone out there.

Answer (score 3):

Set a breakpoint in there to see exactly which XML node it's choking on.  My guess is that you may have broken the config with some bad XML in a custom module.

The place it's choking is:

```
public function getGroupedClassName($groupType, $classId, $groupRootNode=null)
{
    ...
    $config = $this->_xml->global->{$groupType.'s'}->{$group};
```

Answer (score 3):

This notice happened to me when an unfulfilled module-dependency caused an exception.

The exception-handler then looked for the helper *core/data* to translate the exception-message whose *config.xml* was not loaded in this early stage.
So the xml-node *config/global/helpers* was missing at all.

**Solution**: Try to have a look up higher in the stack to find probably missed module-dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like magento cannot read files in `app/etc` folder

it needs to read `app/etc/config.xml` and `app/etc/local.xml`

In linux try following to fix permission

```
find app/etc -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \;
find app/etc -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Comment: Do not set your directories to 777 and files to 666 unless you want the whole world snooping through your website! Try 755 for directories and 644 for files to make sure everything works while keeping a bit of privacy.

Comment: @DukeDylan well, it's free real state \0/

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me once when I forgot to run "`composer install`" so this came down to module dependencies that were not met.